# Infinispan throws this exception

Tags: exception, infinispan

Are there any open issues or bugs with Infinispan?

Infinispan throws this exception.

```
2014-07-08 14:06:26.935 CEST [{default}_{IdManager.Pool.Global}-FileCacheStore-0] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{IdManager.Pool.Global} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:27.114 CEST [{default}_{IdManager.Pool.Local}-FileCacheStore-1] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{IdManager.Pool.Local} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:27.129 CEST [{default}_{IdManager.AllocatedEntry}-FileCacheStore-2] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{IdManager.AllocatedEntry} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:27.141 CEST [{default}_{IdManager.BladeId}-FileCacheStore-3] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{IdManager.BladeId} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:27.153 CEST [{default}_{IdManager.AppId}-FileCacheStore-4] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{IdManager.AppId} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:46.395 CEST [{default}_{tenants.id}-FileCacheStore-5] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{tenants.id} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:46.594 CEST [{default}_{logicalport.id}-FileCacheStore-6] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{logicalport.id} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:46.622 CEST [{default}_{logicalport.tag}-FileCacheStore-7] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{logicalport.tag} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:46.667 CEST [{default}_{elan.ids}-FileCacheStore-8] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{elan.ids} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:46.733 CEST [{default}_{scfinstance.ids}-FileCacheStore-9] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{scfinstance.ids} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
2014-07-08 14:06:46.749 CEST [{default}_{scfport.ids}-FileCacheStore-10] ERROR o.i.loaders.AbstractCacheStore - ISPN000045: Problems encountered while purging expired
org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderException: File /opt/sdnc/opendaylight/{default}_{scfport.ids} is not directory or IO error occurred when listing files with filter org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore$NumericNamedFilesFilter@5e81430b [fileExists=true, isDirector=true, canRead=true, canWrite=true]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.listFilesStrict(FileCacheStore.java:459) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore.purgeInternal(FileCacheStore.java:218) ~[na:na]
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
```

Comment: Odd, what Infinispan version is this? What is the events that have lead to this? Did you store data in these directories with the same Infinispan version? Don't think the name of those directories is right..., what is the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the permissions for the directory or you can try to use sudo